# Automate sending outlook calendar invites

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I'm given a task to leverage the existing orchestrator(HPOO) automate sending calendar invites periodically based on the data given to me in an Excel sheet. While gathering the data from the Excel is easy, I'm unable to find a way to send the calendar invites automatically. Here are the solutions I have assessed so far and the challenges in each of those:

1. Use comobject outlook.application: While this is easiest of all, the challenge is that I do not have an instance of outlook/office running the server where this automation would run.
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started : This requires an app to be registered (OAuth based auth) and it looks like an overkill for a simple automation

Are there any simple APIs to authenticate instantly(Basic auth, probably) with the account the invite is sent from and directly send the calendar invite ?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any simple APIs to authenticate instantly(Basic auth, probably) with the account the invite is sent from and directly send the calendar invite ?

Basic authentication is being phased out and is best avoided https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange-Team-Blog/Upcoming-changes-to-Exchange-Web-Services-EWS-API-for-Office-365/ba-p/608055

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started : This requires an app to be registered (OAuth based auth) and it looks like an overkill for a simple automation

Its takes maybe a minute to create a application registration in the Azure portal which can then allow the administrators of the tenant to track and audit the usage of your app (and stop your application if needed). So this isn't overkill its best practice for a number of good reasons.

As for the API look at the Graph API https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph then you have one endpoint that can both access the Excel spreadsheet and and send the calendar invites without any need for an underlying office installation.